# How to make a selection sort without using the compare() method in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Greetings StackOverFlow Community!

I have recently started studying java at school, and one of the assignments is to create a sorting method, like selection sort or insertion sort, without using java's own built-in functions. I have looked online a lot, and all of the methods I have found are for Arrays and not ArrayLists. The goal with the assignment is to sort a dog class after tail length, and if the dogs have the same tail length, to also sort after name.
So far this is what I have done;

Dog Class

```
public class Dog {
private static final double DEFAULT_TAIL_SIZE = 10.0;
private static final double DEFAULT_TAX_SIZE = 3.7;
private static int count;
private String name;
private String breed;
private int age;
private int weight;
private double tailLenght;


public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight) {
    //count++;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.tailLenght = tailLenght;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    age = age <= 0 ? 1 : age;
}

public double getTailLength() {
    if (breed.equals("Tax") || breed.equals("dachshund")||breed.equals("tax") || breed.equals("Dachshund")) {
        return tailLenght = DEFAULT_TAX_SIZE;
    } else {
        return tailLenght = age * weight/DEFAULT_TAIL_SIZE;
    }

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    //System.out.println(String.format("name=%s breed=%s age=%d weight=%d taillenght=%.1f", name, breed, age, weight, getTailLength()));
    return name + " " + breed + " " + age + " " + weight + " " + getTailLength();
}
```

And this is the sorting code I have made, that was not accepted due to the code using in-built java sorting methods. **This is the only code I'm allowed to edit during this assignment**

```
public class DogSorter {

public void sort(ArrayList<Dog> dogs) {
    dogs.sort(new Comparator<Dog>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Dog d1, Dog d2) {
            int comparison = 0;
            comparison = Double.valueOf(d1.getTailLength()).compareTo(d2.getTailLength());
            if (comparison == 0) {
                comparison = String.valueOf(d1.getName()).compareTo(d2.getName());
            }
            return comparison;

        }

    });
}
```

And lastly this is the runner code we received from our teachers

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class DogSorterRunner {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_DOGS = 12;

private static final Random RND = new Random();
private static final String[] NAMES = { "Fido", "Karo", "Molly", "Bella", "Wilma", "Doris", "Sigge", "Charlie",
        "Ludde", "Bamse", "Lassie", "Ronja", "Ratata", "Maki", "Dora", "Luna", "Spike", "Mumsan", "Cherie" };

private static final String[] BREEDS = { "Labrador", "Golden retriever", "Tax", "Dachshund" };

private static String getRandomValueFromArray(String[] array) {
    return array[RND.nextInt(array.length)];
}

private static String randomName() {
    return getRandomValueFromArray(NAMES);
}

private static String randomBreed() {
    return getRandomValueFromArray(BREEDS);
}

private static int randomNumber() {
    return RND.nextInt(10) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int n = 0; n < NUMBER_OF_DOGS; n++) {
        Dog dog = new Dog(randomName(), randomBreed(), randomNumber(), randomNumber());
        dogs.add(dog);
    }

    new DogSorter().sort(dogs);

    for (Dog dog : dogs) {
        System.out.println(dog);
    }
}
```

Any help and feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the assignment is that you should implement `selection` or `insertion` sort by yourself instead of using Java's built-in sort function. That is how you show some knowledge in implementing sorting algorithms.

Here is an example of a selection sort, which is based on your conditions (tail & name) and should give you a feeling of how the functions should look like. To do some more exercise, I suggest that you try to implement insertion sort by yourself.

```
public class DogSorter {

    public void sort(ArrayList<Dog> dogs) {
        dogs.sort(new Comparator<Dog>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Dog d1, Dog d2) {
                int comparison = 0;
                comparison = Double
                        .valueOf(d1.getTailLength())
                        .compareTo(d2.getTailLength());
                if (comparison == 0) {
                    comparison = String
                            .valueOf(d1.getName())
                            .compareTo(d2.getName());
                }
                return comparison;
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectionSort(ArrayList<Dog> dogs) {
        int n = dogs.size();

        // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
            int min_idx = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                Dog d1 = dogs.get(j);
                Dog d2 = dogs.get(min_idx);
                int comparison = Double
                        .valueOf(d1.getTailLength())
                        .compareTo(d2.getTailLength());
                if (comparison == 0) {
                    comparison = String
                            .valueOf(d1.getName())
                            .compareTo(d2.getName());
                }
                if (comparison < 0)
                    min_idx = j;
            }

            // Swap the found minimum element with the first
            // element

            // using built in swap
            // Collections.swap(dogs, min_idx, i);

            // using classic temp method
            Dog temp = dogs.get(min_idx);
            dogs.set(min_idx, dogs.get(i));
            dogs.set(i, temp);

            // using classic method without temp element
            // dogs.set(i, dogs.set(min_idx, dogs.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also a repl, where you can see this function in practice: https://repl.it/repls/VividMeekPlans

Comment: Is there any way to re-write the `Collections.swap(dogs, min_idx, i);` at the end? The school compiler is really strict about us not using a finished java method. I tried to make my own method but none of the code complies then..

`int temp = dogs.get(i);
            dogs.set(i, dogs.get(j));
            dogs.set(j, temp);`

Comment: I changed the `int temp` to `Dog temp` but then I get compilation problems such as **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12**

Comment: You can do this using this code:
Dog temp = dogs.get(min_idx);
dogs.set(min_idx, dogs.get(i));
dogs.set(i, temp);
I have also updated the code in my comment above with one more example.

Comment: This was really helpful!! Thank you so much :) <3